# Why does the green "+" button in Mac apps only maximize the height?

Tags: mac-os-x, window

What is the user experience reason for maximizing only the height of a window in Mac OS applications? The green "+" button only maximizes the height in most programs, with no change to the width. Is this really a better user experience?

[image: Mac program control buttons]

The "-" and "x" buttons work as I would expect. I end up resorting to third-party tools to make snapping and maximizing windows easier (one of the few UI things that, in my opinion, Windows got right). What gives?

Comment: Just wondering: which third-party tools do you use for this?

Comment: @DanielGibbs I use Cinch, but there may be others.

Comment: @DanielGibbs BetterSnapTool. It's slightly glitchy with multiple monitors sometimes but for the most part works pretty well.

Comment: I use `Command-Shift-F`, although it moves the window to another desktop, so I often press it again when I'm done to get back where I was.  During the transition effect I whistle [the free software song](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g2cF4-tHvqI)

Comment: To add some history, MacOS *never* had 'maximized' application windows. It was always a multi-windowed UI unlike Windows, which did have fully maximized app window concept.

Comment: @DanielGibbs I can also recommend [Moom](http://manytricks.com/moom) for working with multiple windows. It seems to work in any application, including Windows apps running in Parallels Coherence mode

Comment: press the green button while holding shift-opt, it should do the trick.

Comment: @guenis Woah, that does it.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**Update: In Mac OS X 10.10 Yosemite and later, it seems the zoom button has been replaced by the fullscreen button. The green widget no longer contains a plus sign, but two outward-pointing arrows, and places the window in fullscreen mode. To zoom a window, you now option-click this button.**

[image: Yosemite's three window widgets, close, collapse and fullscreen]

---

The green button isn't for maximizing. If you want to maximize, use the "fullscreen" button in the upper right of the window:

[image: Fullscreen button on a window]

The zoom button is intended to make the window the best possible size that shows the most of the window's content. This is the most useful when working with multiple windows, because you see as much as your screen will hold, but it still leaves enough room in which you can position other windows. (E.g. I often have a Twitter client or chat program open on the right hand side next to the browser)

This feature is especially useful in very old (like the Finder in System 7) or very new applications (i.e. ones that support state restoration) because those will reliably remember the previous position where you put a window. So when you restart your Mac, your Safari window will open beside the chat window, and your setup will be just the way you left it.

Many applications written in the interval between those two eras will just open a window in the upper left, then keep stacking new windows down and to the right, overlapping that window, and give it a default size. That, of course, defeats the advantage of a reliable position for multiple windows to let you arrange your windows onscreen to optimally fit your content.

For comparison, imagine your desk: you can place sheets of paper on it, all have different sizes, maybe different colors, and they can overlap. Since the human mind is optimized for the physical world, you can jog your memory about which sheet it is, just by seeing the corner or an edge (and thus a hint at its size), its thickness and maybe its color, and a hint of whatever's written on it.

Applications that don't remember the position are like when Mrs. Hudson goes through Sherlock Holmes's apartment every morning, dusting off everything and neatly stacking stuff. It is no longer in the position he remembers from last night, and as they're all stacked on top of each other, you can't see it peek out to judge its size, color or content either. Zooming is optimized to support that workflow, make window sizes more unique.

The problem with web browsers is that they use one window for different content, and don't remember window sizes. Thus, the only way to use them without going mad is to make them the size of the screen. Otherwise you'd have to manually resize them every time.

Comment: Definitely the most direct and thorough answer so far about the actual UX! Didn't know about some of those little features they built in related to this.

Comment: The fullscreen button wasn’t there 5 years ago. Apple had no excuse for such behavior of the `+` button back then.

Comment: @kinokijuf How so? As Uli points out, the point was to allow you to see multiple windows from multiple apps at the same time (which isn't possible on Windows when the system maximizes the current app), and to use spatial memory to be able to quickly and easily get at them regardless of which one is currently on top. It's a *very good* excuse in my opinion.

Comment: @user1118321 my point is that there was no real way to maximise back then

Comment: @kinokijuf, the green button and its predecessors have never been a "maximize" button.  The intended use has always been "best fit": set the window to its most useful size.  The confusion with "maximize" comes from many windows being most useful when as large as possible.

Comment: @Mark Yes; the fact that they weren't and have never been maximize buttons was a **mistake**. It should have been **different**.

Comment: @IstvanChung Great that the apple propaganda is working on you, but I'm afraid I'll have to disagree. I *need* a maximize button. And I'm not just talking about it because it's on windows, I use it on a very daily basis on GNU/Linux systems ; I just can't let you decide for me what should or shouldn't be in my interface.

Comment: Before the fullscreen button was there, you could click the zoom button with the option key held down to make a window fill the screen.

Comment: It's the fact that Apple added extra buttons to the title bar in OS X that was a mistake. In classic Mac OS we were perfectly happy with a close button and a zoom button and that was your lot ;-)

Comment: @ArlaudPierre If you could read, you would have noticed that I was saying that Mac OS **should have had** a maximize button, and that it was a **mistake** that it didn't. I was arguing **in favor** of a maximize button, and was **criticizing** Apple for not including one.

Comment: @IstvanChung My apologies, I misread you. It's true it always bothered me the very few times I was on Mac OS. And even now I disagree with the choice of putting the fullscreen button where it is and keeping the maximize button that way.

Comment: This is what the "Inside Macintosh" had to say about the "zoom" button, back in the old days of "classic" Mac OS: "Macintosh monitors come in many sizes, and multiple monitors can be configured in many different ways, so applications should never simply assume that the standard state should be as large as the screen. Frequently the monitor is larger, sometimes much larger, than the most useful size for a window. Screen real estate is valuable, so use screen-sized windows only when they make sense." ("Inside Macintosh: Macintosh Human Interface Guidelines, Page 168)

Answer (score 23):

The window expands to fit the content, and don't add additional whitespace like windows OS does.

> Now let’s look at Apple’s website in Safari. Notice the first image below is a very small window with both vertical and horizontal scrollbars. The second image shows what the window looks like after clicking the Zoom button. Again, it takes up all of the vertical space because there was more scrollable content to be seen. The third image illustrates what the screen would look like fully maximized Windows-style.

[image]

[Reference](http://www.macyourself.com/2011/02/06/why-doesnt-mac-os-xs-green-zoom-button-maximize-windows/)

Comment: From the reference - "Try web pages with a different width and it will size the window differently each time, depending on what’s on screen." It seems pretty frustrating to have to re-maximize when clicking to a new page.

Comment: @mikel Agree to that. But you don't have to resize the window using the button or keyboard shortcuts. You can do it manually :-)

Comment: @BennySkogberg, what is "manually"? should i physically grab the window borders and try and stretch it with my fingers?

Comment: Interesting! I guess apps have to support that kind of viewport sizing then. In my opinion, though, zooming the window to full the screen would be a bigger win than not having extra whitespace. Maybe it's just a matter of preference.

Comment: This seems very much like what Android phones do (maybe others) when you double-tap the screen. The screen becomes as wide as the block of content you double-tapped. Of course, almost all apps are always full-screen, so you're zooming in, not making the window bigger. Still, I wonder if this was inspired by OS X?

Comment: iOS does that too, so most likely inspired by iOS. Not that I'm claiming Apple invented it...